# How to identify <li> tags for which those don't have the style attribute?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a scenario where there is a table and when I search that table i will get a result set and I need to verify whether the search data is available in search result or not.I have around 1000 li tags and the only way to verify the result set by its attribute 'style'. for result set, there is no 'style' attribute in li tags.

```
public boolean isAttribtuePresent(WebElement element, String attribute) {
    Boolean ATTRIB_PRESENT = true;

    try {
        String value = element.getAttribute(attribute);
        if (value.isEmpty() || value == "" || value == null) {
            ATTRIB_PRESENT = true;          
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        ATTRIB_PRESENT = false; 
    }

    return ATTRIB_PRESENT;
}
```

I tried with this but it is validating all LI tags

Comment: <li style="display: none;" class="ui-selectlistbox-item ui-corner-all">AC We Also Found  (Std. JobID: 4)</li>

Comment: <li class="ui-selectlistbox-item ui-corner-all">ADL  (Std. ProcID: 1)</li>                     This LI tag don't have the style attribute

Comment: I'm confused by your tags: the code you're showing is Java, not Javascript. Can you please edit your post?

Comment: none of them have an attribute of "style" and you are returning ATTRIB_PRESENT = true;  I don't think an exception would ever be thrown there since you are using getAttribute method which returns the value (of property or attribute) or null. It does not throw...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: after testing it, this should do the trick:

```java
private boolean isStyleAttributePresent(WebElement element) {
    String attributeValue = element.getAttribute("style");
    return attributeValue != null && !attributeValue.isEmpty();
}
```

---

Old answer:

Looking [at the docs of the getAttribute() method:](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-)

> Returns:
>   The attribute/property's current value or null if the value is not set.

... and assuming that you are looking for the `<li>` without the set `style` attribute, this should do the trick:

```java
public boolean isStyleAttributePresent(WebElement element) {
    return element.getAttribute("style") != null;
}
```

---

Demo used to verify the solution:

```java
/* ... */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/kasptom/selenium/chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("file:///home/kasptom/Dev/stack-java-maven/src/main/resources/my_page.html");

    List<WebElement> lis = driver.findElements(By.tagName("li"));

    List<WebElement> lisWithNoStyle = lis.stream()
            .filter(SeleniumLiDemo::isStyleAttributePresent)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.format("Number of <li> detected %d, with no style %d%n", lis.size(), lisWithNoStyle.size());
}

private static boolean isStyleAttributePresent(WebElement element) {
    String attributeValue = element.getAttribute("style");
    return attributeValue != null && attributeValue.isEmpty();
}
/* ... */
```

my_page.html

```html
<html>
<body>
<ul>
    <li class="ui-selectlistbox-item ui-corner-all">ADL (Std. ProcID: 1)</li>
    <li style="display: none" class="ui-selectlistbox-item ui-corner-all">ADL (Std. ProcID: 1)</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, I tried this but it is resulting the same.. it is selecting all the li tags. the one which i want to select is that is  the below  which don't have style att                                                        
 <li class="ui-selectlistbox-item ui-corner-all">ADL (Std. ProcID: 1)</li>

Comment: @Syed Ahmed, I've tested it and you are right. Somehow the style is returned as an empty string.